# plus-minus symbol with parenthesis around the minus sign

Tags: symbols

I need one (or maybe two) LaTeX symbols that I don't find in the comprehensive list of symbols. The symbol is like the normal plus-minus sign `\pm`, but with parenthesis around the minus sign. Is such a symbol available somewhere? And if not, what is the best way to construct it from `(`, `\pm` and `)`?

Preferably I would also want the opposite: `\mp` with parenthesis around the plus.

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide a citation to where these symbols can be found in published material, and also say what they are used for and provide a meaningful name.  they are not in unicode.  send this information also to `tech-support@ams.org`; i am the representative of the stix project to unicode, and if suitable documentation is provided, i will communicate uncoded symbols to them for consideration.

Comment: @barbara: I actually asked because a friend asked me about it, so I'm not sure of the context in which is was needed. I'll check if he has any references. I think I've seen such a symbol in basic math or physics textbooks, eg, to indicate that a quadratic equation has two roots of different signs, but only the positive root is of (say physical) interest.

Comment: I did a web search for this symbol and found this discussion. This kind of a symbol is very useful when neglecting, say, negative (or positive) solutions to quadratic equations because of known constraints. I use it often in my teaching. How extensive would the list of pointers to literature have to be in order for the symbol to be considered to be added?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I once proposed the following definitions

```
\newcommand\varpm{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{\hfil$\scriptstyle+$\hfil\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          $\scriptscriptstyle({-})$\cr}%
}}}}
\newcommand\varmp{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{$\scriptstyle({+})$\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          \hfil$\scriptscriptstyle-$\hfil\cr}%
}}}}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\varpm{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{\hfil$\scriptstyle+$\hfil\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          $\scriptscriptstyle({-})$\cr}%
}}}}
\newcommand\varmp{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{$\scriptstyle({+})$\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          \hfil$\scriptscriptstyle-$\hfil\cr}%
}}}}

\begin{document}
$a\varpm b\varmp c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this still the 'best' solution out there? I find the vertical gap between + and - too large, and would like the parentheses to be smaller and somewhat denser.

Comment: @Jost You can reduce the spacing with `\kern-0.5ex`. About the parentheses, it would be possible to reduce them too, but I'm not sure it's worth trying.

Comment: You can add ``\hspace{-0.1ex}`` between the ``+`` sign to make the parentheses denser.

Comment: @yoki `\mkern-3mu` or so.

Comment: I'd replace \scriptstyle by \scriptscriptstyle